# How do I return values of one class method to another class method?

Tags: python-3.x, class, object, queue, self

I am new to Classes and want to know how to return values from one class method to another. Below is the code and I want to return the queues from arrive() function to next_customer() function.

```
class DonutQueue():

        def __init__(self):

            self.queue=[]
            self.queue2= []

        def arrive(self,name,vip):

            self.name = name
            self.vip = vip
            if self.vip==1:
                self.queue2.append(self.name)
                return self.queue2
            else:
                self.queue.append(self.name)
                return self.queue
        
        def next_customer(self):
    
            while not self.queue2== []:
                if not self.queue2==[]:
                    return self.queue
                else:
                    return self.queue2

def main():

    n = int(input("Enter the number of customers you want to add"))

    for i in range(0,n):
        name = input("Enter their name")
        vip= int(input("Are they a VIP"))
        DonutQueue().arrive(name,vip)

    print(DonutQueue().next_customer())
```

If I add the below statement in the next_customer function, I get the mentioned error:

```
a = self.arrive(self.name,self.vip)
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'DonutQueue' object has no attribute 'name'
```

The problem is when I call next_customer() it returns None because I am getting values from **init** instead of arrives()

Answer (score 0):

in python you have to define members in the `__init__` function means. in your case you defined the `self.name` member only in `arrive` thats why its not available (and throws an exception) in your case.